# Woocommerce Login: If user account does not exist, display error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Currently when a user attempts to login with an email/username which does not exist, this default woocommerce error is displayed:

[image]

I am trying check: **If email/username DOES NOT exist, display different message**.

e.g. *"No account exists with this email, please create one."*

The hook `woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists` checks if a user tried to register with an email which already exists, so I am trying to reverse this with `!email_exists` - Can this be applied to the login field?

My code below is not triggering and still displays the default message:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', 'no_account_found' );

function no_account_found($email, $username = '', $password = '' ){

  if ( !email_exists( $email ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-email-exists', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', __( 'No account found with this email. Please create one.', 'woocommerce' ), $email ) );
        }
}
```

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists` **is only used for account creation** and also doesn't need `email_exists()` as the filter is already using that by itself  (you can see that [in the source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_new_customer.html#53))…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Understood, so it cannot be used to perform checks on the **login**? Or perhaps another hook?

Answer (score 1):

`email_exists( string $email )` returns the user's ID on success, and false on failure.

So try change your condition like this :

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', 'no_account_found' );

function no_account_found($email, $username = '', $password = '' ){

  if (email_exists($email) ) {

            //the email exists do something
        }else{
            //email does not exist
            return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-email-exists', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', __( 'No account found with this email. Please create one.', 'woocommerce' ), $email ) );          
        }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be having an effect. Do the `login` and `register` fields behave differently?